# What is the meaning of 'pass the lips of native speakers'?

Tags: meaning

I saw the sentence like 'pass the lips of native speakers'.
What is the meaning of 'pass the lips of native speakers'?

Comment: I believe you need to add a little more context. The sentence is vague as it looks incomplete.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pass-one's-lips

Answer (score 1):

The expression "pass one's lips" is used in a negative sense to express the idea of saying, eating or drinking something is that is abhorrent (polite people and bad language, vegetarians and meat, muslims and alcohol). It can also be used about keeping a very important secret.

Your phrase might occur in a sentence like:

Something like that would never pass the lips of a native English speaker.

What this means is that a native English speaker would never **ever** say something like that.

Comment: I think it should be noted that while this phrase definitely has a negative connotation, it doesn't *strictly* refer to abstention [from saying/eating/drinking something]. You could say "this phrase often passes the lips of native speakers" **but** this would be an unusual usage.